# GIS project advice

Tags: gis, openlayers, postgis, mapserver

Hello:
I have the following:
1. Shapefile of the world with the boundaries of each country
-- Successfully imported shapefile into PostGIS database
   -- Can display map of the world in a browser via Openlayers.

2  A data (CSV) file where each record has
   a. birth country,
   b. gender,
   c. lat and long of the country of birth (which matches the lat & long in the shapefile)

I am trying to figure out the best approach to display a map where each country (based on the CSV data) that has a 100 or more people with a color say red or green....

So my question is:
If I create a separate table with the CSV data, is there a way link this table with the shapefile table to do the above?

OR

Do I need to merge the CSV data into the shapefile table in order to accomplish the above

I am using PostGIS, mapserver and Openlayers

Thanks
Chris

Comment: I guess http://gis.stackexchange.com/ would be more appropriate for this question

Comment: I'll check that website....
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I would import data from CSV file to the same PostGIS database and then create a view on two tables that would have country name and number of people(calculated from data in CSV file).

Then I would create a WMS in Mapserver from this view with SLD where I specify which color every country gets depending on number of people.

Comment: Igorti:  
I see what you're saying....  
It's a static set of data so I can use a table instead of a view....  
I have a question about the shape file... I looked at the associated dbf file I don't see a geometry column.  
So how do I find the geometry for each country?  
Chris

Comment: one addition; Don't forget to add an entry to the VIEW in your geometry_columns table: http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ch04.html#id2759271

Answer (score 0):

You can import a Sharefile into geoserver and geoserver will provide a WMS resource that OpenLayers can read.

I am not too sure about how to integrate CSV data b/c it has been a while.  Perhaps you can just make each country have its own DOM id and just alter CSS with different background-color after map is rendered using javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... But I'm using mapserver on this project... Based on another suggestion, I'll import the CSV file as table and get at what I want via a SELECT statement that get data from both tables... Chris

Answer (score 0):

@chris the .dbf file should have non-geographic data such as the data about birth country and gender.

Another good example is a Shapefile from US Census Bureau.  Typically the dbf file will have Census data / demographic data; but not geographic data.